# Can I use my IP address as a IRC server address?

Tags: ip-address, irc

If I'm making an IRC server of my own, can I use my IP address as the server address? Will other people be able to connect to my server using my IP as the server address?

Comment: There's no way we could possibly know whether or not this will work since we know absolutely nothing about your setup.

Answer (score 3):

If you provide the public rather than [private IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) for your server to others, it may be accessible to others provided you modify the configuration of your router/firewall to allow connectivity in on the relevant port and forward connectivity to the system that you have set up as a IRC server behind that router/firewall. You can determine your public IP address by visiting a site such as [WhatIsMyIP.com](http://whatismyip.com) from the system you will be using as the IRC server. That is the IP address you will need to provide to others.

The exact steps you will need to take to set up the [port forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding), assuming your router/firewall is performing [network address translation (NAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), will depend on the manufacturer and model of the router/firewall that provides Internet access at your location. Refer to the documentation for the router/firewall for determining those steps. You will need to configure the router/firewall to allow connectivity in on the [relevant network port for IRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat#Technical_information).

If you have host-based [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) software on the system that will be functioning as the IRC server, e.g., [Windows Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_firewall) for a Windows system or [iptables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables) or [FirewallD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FirewallD) on a Linux system, you will also need to configure that firewall software to allow connectivity through to the IRC server software on the system.

As davidgo mentioned, if your [Internet Service Provider (ISP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISP) assigns you a dynamic IP address via the [Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol), your public IP address may not be constant, but may change from time to time. If that occurs, you will need a way to notify everyone using your server that the [IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) has changed. That may be possible if there are a small number of people who use the server and you have a way of notifying them easily, but if you want the server to be accessible to people throughout the Internet or don't want to have to notify all users of the system whenever the IP address changes, then you need to use a [Dynamic DNS (DDNS or DynDNS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) solution.

The way a DDNS service ensures that a system with a DHCP-provided address is accessible to others even when its IP address changes is that you install software on your system that communicates with the DDNS service, or you configure a router/firewall that sits in front of the system hosting your server to send its IP address to the DDNS service provider periodically, so that the DDNS service knows the current IP address of your system. So whenever someone puts a [fully qualified domain name (FQDN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) in his or her browser address field, e.g., `ambersServer.example.com`, his/her system attempts to look up the IP address associated with the FQDN, one of the DDNS service provider's [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) servers are queried and returns the current address assigned to your IRC server.

For the domain name for your server, you can purchase a domain name, e.g. `amber.com`, if it was available, from a [domain name registrar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_registrar); you can find registrar's that will sell a domain name for $10 [USD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_dollar) or less for a year. Or there are DDNS service providers that will allow you to use one of their domain names for free. I use [No-IP.com](http://www.noip.com/) for DDNS service, but there are other such services you can use, e.g., [DynDNS](http://dyn.com/remote-access/). No-IP allows you to point to any of several domain names they own for free, e.g., you could use `amber.ddns.net`, if no one else was using that [hostname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname), etc. If you purchase your own domain name, then you can set the DNS servers for it to point to the DDNS provider's DNS servers; you would need to purchase DDNS service for the domain name, so, for someone unfamiliar with configuring DNS support, it would be easier to register the domain name through the DDNS service provider, though you can choose the free option if it isn't import to you to have your own, unique domain name.

Comment: Good answer.  You may want to add something about using dyndns or equivalent to provide a domain name which can be used in place of an IP address in the case that the IP address is dynamically assigned.

Comment: heh. Once again, I've been beaten to an answer with 90% of what I'd say, good show!. Its worth remembering/stating that IRC is pretty primitive and does not actually care about the hostname you use.